# How to get the number of occurrences in another table

Tags: sql

If I have `TABLE_A`:

```
A_ID  B_ID
 1     6
 2     6
 3     7
 4     7
 5     7
```

and `TABLE_B`:

```
B_ID B_NAME
 6     B1
 7     B2
 8     B3
 9     B4
```

How can I find the number of occurrences of `B_ID` in `TABLE_A`? Something like this:

`select B_ID, B_NAME, total_count from TABLE_B`

Where "total_count" is the number of times `B_ID` is found in `TABLE_A` so that the result would be:

```
B_ID B_NAME total_count
 6     B1        2
 7     B2        3
 8     B3        0
 9     B4        0
```

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by`, `left join` and `count`:

```
SELECT B.B_ID, B.B_NAME, COUNT(A.A_Id) As TotalCount
FROM TableB As B
LEFT JOIN TableA As A
    ON B.B_ID = A.B_ID
GROUP BY B.B_ID, B.B_NAME
```

This is quite a basic query in SQL, and should produce the same result on most if not all relational databases.